# Unable to publish Azure Data Factory using GIT sync due to Data Factory mode?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So our project has been using Azure Data Factory with GIT integration for about a year without issues.

We just encountered one I need help with.

The data factory pulls in its changes from GIT. So usually we just check in / merge branches, and then I go to the portal and press publish new changes and it works fine.

Everything looked normal, but this time it failed because there was a pipeline referencing a deleted dataset.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivk0v.png

I looked but couldn't find the pipeline in the project or my git repo's json files.

Finally I realized there was this button to switch over to "DataFactory" mode. I assume this was the old mode we used before we set up GIT?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fFYx.png

In this mode I found the pipeline that was causing the failure, deleted it, but then I can't actually save the delete because I am not allowed to publish from Data Factory mode with GIT sync enabled.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAqGD.png

So I seem to be in a holding pattern, can't publish from GIT to deploy code due to DataFactory mode, yet I can't fix DataFactory mode because I have GIT enabled.

I suppose I could disable the GIT sync, fix the DF mode, and renable the git sync but I am worried that might break something else.

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I looked but couldn't find the pipeline in the project or my git
> repo's json files.
>
> In this mode I found the pipeline that was causing the failure,
> deleted it, but then I can't actually save the delete because I am not
> allowed to publish from Data Factory mode with GIT sync enabled.

It seems your data between Git mode and Data Factory mode isn't synchronize. You can try to import existing resources to repository.
[image]

> I suppose I could disable the GIT sync, fix the DF mode, and renable
> the git sync.

I think this way can work and it won't break something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can disconnect the GIT repository, delete the pipeline from data factory mode, publish and re-connect to GIT. Make sure to import the existing resources to repo when you reconnect with GIT.